# PDF rendering issue os OSX

Tags: macos, pdf, rendering

I came across some very odd rendering when trying to view a PDF file that needed to print out. I was wondering anyone has come across a similar problem before or has any ideas as to what might be causing this.

PDF when viewed on OSX 10.7.4 - Preview version 6.0. I've tried opening the file in Skim but that doesn't work either.

[image]

PDF as it should be, and as Chrome renders it in browser, but not if I download it onto my machine.

[image]

Illustrator complains about "an unknown imaging construct" when I open the file, but renders it fine nevertheless, Photoshop doesn't have any problems either.

**UPDATE:**
Note that I'm not generating the PDF myself, it's a standard Springer-Verlag Consent to Publish form created by Springer. The file meta data says it has been created with MS Office Word 2007 and exported for Acrobat 6.x, there is no security and there are two fonts embedded

- Arial (TrueType CID, Encoding: Identity-H)
- Times New Roman (TrueType,
  Encoding: ANSI, ActualFont: TimesNewRomanPSMT)

The PDF is accessible online [here](http://www.bcs-sgai.org/ai2012/springer/ai2012_ctp_form.pdf)

Comment: Did you manually resize these image, or are you viewing these files thumbnail-sized?

Comment: 1. what is the font you are using? and does is allow embedding into PDF files? 2. are you use text with gradient color filling? 3. what is the software that exported your PDF?

Comment: @DanielBeck I've resized the images for the post

Comment: @Servant see update above

Comment: If it's a standard consent to publish agreement PDF, and not private, could you maybe upload it somewhere?

Comment: @DanielBeck added link to PDF file

Comment: Cannot repro the issue on OS X 10.8. Have you tried [clearing your fonts cache](http://superuser.com/questions/218269/how-to-clear-font-cache-in-mac/218287#218287)?

Comment: @DanielBeck reset font cache still same problem

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue with with PDF-files generated with Microsoft Office. The only way to get that PDF file displayed correctly was to use the Adobe Reader.

It seems to be an issue with a windows font that is not embedded in the PDF-File that does not correctly render in some rendering engines.

The only engine that comes around that issue AFAIK is Adobe Reader.

Comment: I am starting to think the same thing. Opening the file in Adobe Reader works fine. Although OSX 10.8. doesn't have the problem.

Comment: It's an issue with the renderer in OSX < 10.8 that does not correctly render the file. Well - and probably Office that does not embed the font.....

Answer (score 1):

i noticed that there is no fonts appear in the document however acrobat appear that there is two fonts used in the document and only Times new roman is not embedded at all.

[image]

zoom in your document and the truth will reveal.

all text in your document are pixelated. which mean that the rendering to PDF is wrong. and it did embedded any font at all.

[image]